# Help identifying a style consisting of only basic shapes, like Flat design but more rudimentary

Tags: style-identification, style, flat-design

Recently, I have been seeing more and more examples of some kind of design style consisting only of rudimentary basic shapes, leaving out as much detail as possible. It's been used for many things, but mostly to illustrate UI.

The following examples could be classified as **flat design**, but I'm feeling it's not *just* that. Maybe it's a sub-style or kindred style? **Can anyone help me put a name to this style?** Maybe *Flat Design Blocked*? Or *Flat without details*?

---

Some examples:

**Treehouse** shows this a lot

[image: Treehouse Flat blocks]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH37O.png)

Also **Adobe** has been using this style as of late in some of their help docs

[image: Illustrator Flat Design Block]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZJ7O.png)

Comment: Turning stuff, especially text, into boxes in software (including InDesign) is called [Greeking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name of the web design pattern of showing the shape of content while actual content is loading?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96402/whats-the-name-of-the-web-design-pattern-of-showing-the-shape-of-content-while)

Comment: @Luciano Its very close unfortunately the Question as well as the answers are focussed on using this particular graphic style in the context of a loading UX point of view.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard it referred to as [blockframing](https://www.uxpower.tools/blockframe-heroes/), as in wireframes with block elements.

Answer (score 2):

The dashes are usually used in wireframe designs and scamps. I would call this a flat design mockup concept.

When I ran a search I came across this http://www.titanui.com/17339-flat-designed-mobile-cooking-app-wireframe-psd/

Hope it answers your doubt

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's a reasonable name except it can be a misnomer since this design trend is used in production (and not just in wire frames) all over the internet including my examples .

Comment: Perhaps you can call it low fidelity flat design. Fidelity itself is a photoshop term

Comment: When I googled low fidelity mockup I ended up with a result which matches the expectation. https://dribbble.com/shots/1278602-Low-fidelity-wireframes

Comment: [Fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity) isn't a Photoshop term... it is a term used in many many context.

Comment: CAI: Iam pretty sure I came across FIDILITY in my lifetime. I am sure the moderator of this post understood what I meant. It is an option in Photoshop and hence it is okay to use it as a name for this design.

Comment: No I agree, low-fidelity is something you could use to describe this. Your comment sounded like you were saying fidelity is a term limited to Photoshop, I was just pointing out that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's a concept taken from something called block framing which is simply creating something out of blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You will find similar results when looking for '**Low Fidelity**' icons, wireframes etc. The style comes from low fidelity wireframes, used in the early design process to roughly sketch out the flow of a product.

However lately you see a lot of icons in this **minimal** style and I have found a lot of these icons are labeled as '**minimal flat design**' too.

It does indeed fall under **flat design** as well, and you will find many similar results when looking for flat icons.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers collectively point out...there is no single term for this.

Adjectives to describe it could include

- flat
- simplified
- iconinc
- geometric
- wireframed
- low-fi(delity)

Like most good branding, it's merely a style that was replicated throughout their branding and that is the key...less so than what the actual style might be called or based on.

Answer (score 0):

if such figures are hand drawn its called "LOW FI PROTOTYPES" ..so i think in your case it might be called "LOW FI PROTOTYPE VECTOR".. but still im not sure about that

But recently i was also in search of such elements and i stumbled upon some such elements in themeforest.
https://themeforest.net/item/madkit-lowfi-prototypes-uxui-kit/15693066

Hope this helps

Comment: LO-FI just means at it's most basic level, typically being drawn in outlines or looking like a sketch.